# Refactoring nested for each loop

Tags: javascript, json, refactoring, lodash

I have below code to iterated the stickers info from object. For that I am using two nested for each. Is there any better method in lodash to refactor below code without using nested forEach or any better suggestion.

```
var stickers = [];
_.forEach(data.families.categories, function (category) {
    _.forEach(category.stickers, function (sticker) {
        stickers.push(sticker);
    });
});
```

Below is the object sample

```
var data = {
  "families": {
    "id": "my_family",
    "categories": [
      {
        "label": "sample-1",
        "id": "family-0",
        "stickers": [
          "aa",
          "bb",
          "cc"
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "US",
        "id": "family-1",
        "stickers": [
          "DD",
          "EE"
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "sample-2",
        "id": "family-2",
        "stickers": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "sample-3",
        "id": "family-3",
        "stickers": [
          "FF",
          "GG",
          "HH",
          "II",
          "JJ"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: why negative vote ... please suggest negative voter

Comment: I  would do this with a map and array concatenation in reduce.

Comment: but why negative vote?....This is my question how we can improve above code. Can you suggest me with some snippet and examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lodash provides the [**flatMap**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#flatMap) function which will do what you want:

```
var stickers =_.flatMap(data.families.categories, 'stickers');
```

```js
 var data = {
  "families": {
    "id": "my_family",
    "categories": [
      {
        "label": "sample-1",
        "id": "family-0",
        "stickers": [
          "aa",
          "bb",
          "cc"
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "US",
        "id": "family-1",
        "stickers": [
          "DD",
          "EE"
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "sample-2",
        "id": "family-2",
        "stickers": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "sample-3",
        "id": "family-3",
        "stickers": [
          "FF",
          "GG",
          "HH",
          "II",
          "JJ"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
    
    var stickers =_.flatMap( data.families.categories, 'stickers');

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(stickers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in combination with [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
var data = { "families": { "id": "my_family", "categories": [{ "label": "sample-1", "id": "family-0", "stickers": ["aa", "bb", "cc"] }, { "label": "US", "id": "family-1", "stickers": ["DD", "EE"] }, { "label": "sample-2", "id": "family-2", "stickers": [] }, { "label": "sample-3", "id": "family-3", "stickers": ["FF", "GG", "HH", "II", "JJ"] }] } },
    stickers = data.families.categories.reduce(function (r, category) {
        return r.concat(category.stickers);
    }, []);

console.log(stickers);
```